# Creating field with specified slope projecting from 3D polygon?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst

I am trying to figure out how to create a elevation raster from a known location (3D polygon) that projects at a specified slope (1%) for a specified distance(1-2 km).

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiply the polygon's Euclidean distance grid by 1/100.  This slope will increase away from the polygon.  To make the slope *decrease* downwards from the polygon, multiply by -1/100 rather than +1/100.  An illustration (for a polyline rather than a polygon, but the method is identical) is given in another thread at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/17805.

To obtain the specified limiting distance, you will get a lot of control by creating a mask for the Euclidean Distance calculation.  For instance, use a 2000 m buffer of the polygon as the mask.

To place the polygon at a fixed elevation, add that elevation to the previous result.  Thus, for example, a Map Algebra expression might look like

```
Slope = 300 - (1/100) * [Euclidean distance to polygon]
```

When the polygon boundary is at varying elevations, convert those elevations to a categorical (integer) grid if necessary.  (Reduce the discretization effect by rounding to the nearest 1/10 or 1/100 of a meter if you like.)

[image: Integral elevations]

As before, compute the Euclidean distance grid.

[image: Distance grid]

Also compute the Euclidean allocation grid for the boundary: the values in this grid give the elevations of the nearest polygon cell.

[image: Euclidean allocation grid]

Now perform the same subtraction as before, as in

```
Slope = [Euclidean allocation] - (1/100) * [Euclidean distance]
```

[image: Result]

*(The color breakpoints have changed slightly to accommodate the greater range of elevations in the resulting grid.)*

You can see the problems with a varying elevation along the boundary.  They are akin to what is observed in a complicated sloping roof: although the roof may have constant slope everywhere, the ridges and valleys have lower slopes.  Therefore you cannot (usually) obtain a surface of constant slope emanating from the original polygon (unless that polygon's boundary behaves like the intersection of a cone of the desired slope and a right prism based on the polygon).

Comment: If the polygon boundary does not have a constant elevation, you cannot usually get a solution at all.  An approximate solution can be obtained but it's a little involved so I have refrained from specifying it.  Let me know if you need that refinement.

Comment: Hi William - Thanks for responding to this.  The polygons I have are not constant elevation but I think approximate solutions will be fine.  I was thinking of creating a raster field with the known elevations at the center and then using a multi-buffer with widths set at the same increment as the pixel size (10m).  I would then somehow use a nearest neighbor window and calculation (similar to what you have recommended for 2D) to determine incrementally as a person moves through the buffers the new elevations at the prescibed gradient.  The polygons are within larger polygons as a mask.

Comment: I have illustrated one solution, @Ben.