# Estimating the water coverage area behind a dam

Tags: arcgis-desktop, surface, water, arcgis-water-utilities

I have a task to estimate the area that will be covered by water when a dam is built in the provided location. The only thing I have is the max water level calculated for the reservoir.

Is that enough or I will need more details and data?

Can it be done just using GIS tools?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Desktop but are you using the ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap application from that product?  You have another tag for the ArcGIS for Water Utilities solution but are you using that?

Comment: A model of the land elevation in the area and possibly more details about the reservoir. Will it be "lossy" because it is just natural rocks and dirt on the bottom or is it sealed? Yes, a GIS problem. Some flood estimates are too much for ArcGIS and require extra software, but this is simpler.

Comment: The bare minimum you will need in addition to depth is the area covered by water, which you could derive in GIS if you had a good image. Multiplying maximum water depth by area would give you the maximum possible volume though of course areas near the edge and at the upper reaches would tend to zero depth. As @danak says, a model/DTM of the pre-dam topography enables full solution.

Comment: First 'build ' dam using https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17793/how-to-build-an-artificial-dam-across-a-river/17805#17805 and use Fill to estimate flooded area. Con(Fill >Dem,1)